# Beautiful Soup not displaying the text seen on webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am playing around with scraping the website:
https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nba-basketball/merged/?date=20131101

I am trying to pull in the betting lines using beautiful soup, and I can see the results I want when I inspect the page. The problem is when i pull it in I don't see the actual results just a '-'

```
betting_page = requests.get(f'https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nba-basketball/merged/?date=20131101')
betting_page = BeautifulSoup(betting_page.text, 'html.parser')
for item in betting_page.find_all('main', class_='_2ZO4X'):
    print (item.text) #I should see the betting lines here but I only see '-'
```

Any BS4 experts know why bs is not picking up the real text?

Answer (score 0):

You should know that BeautifulSoup can only parse the DOM from the HTML of webpage. However, the statistics you can see in the page is not provided to you via HTML but JSON.

Try getting the real query URL of JSON and you can get the statistics in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the data inside the tables, numbers in columns 1,2,3,4,5,t you are looking into the wrong element The correct way will be

```
for item in betting_page.find_all('div', class_='_1Y3rN'):
   for div in item.find_all('div'):
      print (div.text)
```